# ÆØÅ error in TiKZ

Tags: errors

I am trying to use TikZ to draw a rectangle but I can't use ÆØÅ æøå in the pictures. But it isn't a problem outside of the picture?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

%opening
\title{Formelsamling}
\author{Daniel}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]

\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[sloped,above] {$Hypotonusen\ c=\num{2.0}$} (B) -- node[right] {$Hosliggende \ a=\num{1.5}$} (C) -- node[below] {$Modstående\ b=\num{1,8}$} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should first try `$Modstående\ b=\num{1,8}$` in running text and see that it fails. The text for a node is just that; since you would input `Modstående $b=\num{1,8}$` in running text, the same input should be used for a node text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is that you have the special characters in mathmode, this is what gives the error. My suggestion would be to put the names of the sides in text mode:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[sloped,above] {Hypotonusen $c=\num{2.0}$} (B) -- node[right] {Hosliggende $a=\num{1.5}$} (C) -- node[below] {Modstående $b=\num{1,8}$} (A);
\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DanielGuldbergAaes Hypot*e*nusen